# C# in Javascript Element on CSHTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

How can I use c# code in a Javascript statement?

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById('part1').innerHTML = '' +
'@Html.Partial("SelectCustomer.Views")'
' Views';
```

`@Html.Partial("SelectCustomer.Views")` and `<%=` and `%>` do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Html.Raw("document.getElementById('part1').innerHTML = '' +
 @Html.Partial("SelectCustomer.Views")
 ' Views';");
```

Don't have razor project on hand to test it. Might need to remove the @ from the second Html.